# pdk-test-crypto-perf throughput low using intel QAT

Tags: c++, dpdk

I am doing some dpdk cryptodev tests related to throughout with intel QAT.
When using the dpdk app dpdk-test-crypto-perf , I notice that the throughput is way less than what is mentioned in http://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/DPDK_20_11_Intel_crypto_performance_report.pdf

```
 [root]# ./dpdk-test-crypto-perf --socket-mem 2048,0 --legacy-mem -w 0000:3d:01.0 -w 0000:3d:01.7  -w  0000:3d:02.7 -l 4,5,13,6,14 -n 4 -- --buffer-sz 64,128,256,512,1024,2048 --optype cipher-then-auth --ptest throughput --auth-key-sz 64 --cipher-key-sz 16 --devtype crypto_qat --cipher-iv-sz 16 --auth-op generate --burst-sz 32 --total-ops 30000000 --silent --digest-sz 20 --auth-algo sha1-hmac --cipher-algo aes-cbc --cipher-op encrypt
EAL: Detected 36 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
Option -w, --pci-whitelist is deprecated, use -a, --allow option instead
Option -w, --pci-whitelist is deprecated, use -a, --allow option instead
Option -w, --pci-whitelist is deprecated, use -a, --allow option instead
Option -w, --pci-whitelist is deprecated, use -a, --allow option instead
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: qat (8086:37c9) device: 0000:3d:01.0 (socket 0)
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev 0000:3d:01.0_qat_sym

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: 0000:3d:01.0_qat_sym,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 0
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev 0000:3d:01.0_qat_asym

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: 0000:3d:01.0_qat_asym,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 0
EAL: Probe PCI driver: qat (8086:37c9) device: 0000:3d:01.7 (socket 0)
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev 0000:3d:01.7_qat_sym

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: 0000:3d:01.7_qat_sym,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 0
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev 0000:3d:01.7_qat_asym

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: 0000:3d:01.7_qat_asym,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 0
EAL: Probe PCI driver: qat (8086:37c9) device: 0000:3d:02.7 (socket 0)
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev 0000:3d:02.7_qat_sym

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: 0000:3d:02.7_qat_sym,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 0
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev 0000:3d:02.7_qat_asym

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: 0000:3d:02.7_qat_asym,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 0
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Allocated pool "priv_sess_mp_0" on socket 0
CRYPTODEV: elt_size 0 is expanded to 240

Allocated pool "sess_mp_0" on socket 0
    lcore id    Buf Size  Burst Size    Enqueued    Dequeued  Failed Enq  Failed Deq        MOps        Gbps  Cycles/Buf

          13          64          32    30000000    30000000   608024205   590361292      1.4151      0.7245     2190.68
          14          64          32    30000000    30000000   657459751   640717849      1.4149      0.7244     2190.99
           5          64          32    30000000    30000000   605264521   587610893      1.4148      0.7244     2191.05
           6          64          32    30000000    30000000   657948166   641046769      1.4148      0.7244     2191.08
           6         128          32    30000000    30000000   656326323   639492353      1.4120      1.4459     2195.45
           5         128          32    30000000    30000000   603124442   585311776      1.4116      1.4455     2196.03
          13         128          32    30000000    30000000   606420080   588546448      1.4116      1.4455     2196.11
          14         128          32    30000000    30000000   656535199   639674449      1.4115      1.4454     2196.28
           5         256          32    30000000    30000000   612548897   594307290      1.3874      2.8413     2234.44
           6         256          32    30000000    30000000   661625698   644285343      1.3871      2.8407     2234.91
          14         256          32    30000000    30000000   661348938   644025757      1.3869      2.8403     2235.23
          13         256          32    30000000    30000000   615542904   597231595      1.3868      2.8403     2235.29
          13         512          32    30000000    30000000   648544131   629851341      1.3264      5.4330     2337.10
           6         512          32    30000000    30000000   690157406   672252121      1.3264      5.4328     2337.21
          14         512          32    30000000    30000000   688334849   670537999      1.3260      5.4312     2337.88
           5         512          32    30000000    30000000   646173682   627438866      1.3256      5.4297     2338.55
           5        1024          32    30000000    30000000   787708296   768071019      1.1471      9.3970     2702.48
          13        1024          32    30000000    30000000   792311812   772652910      1.1461      9.3888     2704.84
           6        1024          32    30000000    30000000   829463330   810543251      1.1458      9.3866     2705.48
          14        1024          32    30000000    30000000   828377296   809370537      1.1457      9.3860     2705.65
          13        2048          32    30000000    30000000  1399981574  1379798969      0.7602     12.4550     4077.90
          14        2048          32    30000000    30000000  1437924813  1418541434      0.7601     12.4533     4078.45
           6        2048          32    30000000    30000000  1441794521  1422292353      0.7600     12.4514     4079.11
           5        2048          32    30000000    30000000  1399004014  1378687062      0.7600     12.4512     4079.15
```

Is this expected ? Or is something wrong with my config ? There are a lot of  Failed Enq/Deq as well.

```
[root]# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1127.19.1.rt56.1116.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 intel_pstate=disable idle=poll default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=100 intel_iommu=on iommu=pt selinux=0 enforcing=0 nmi_watchdog=0 audit=0 mce=off kthread_cpus=0,35 irqaffinity=0,35 skew_tick=1 isolcpus=1-34 intel_pstate=disable nosoftlockup nohz=on nohz_full=1-34 rcu_nocbs=1-34
```

If I use sw crypto, I get much better results.

```
[root] # ./dpdk-test-crypto-perf --socket-mem 2048,0 --legacy-mem --vdev crypto_aesni_mb_pmd_1 -l 4,5 -n 4 -- --buffer-sz 64,128,256,512,1024,2048 --optype cipher-then-auth --ptest throughput --auth-key-sz 64 --cipher-key-sz 16 --devtype crypto_aesni_mb --cipher-iv-sz 16 --auth-op generate --burst-sz 32 --total-ops 10000000 --silent --digest-sz 12 --auth-algo sha1-hmac --cipher-algo aes-cbc --cipher-op encrypt
EAL: Detected 6 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev crypto_aesni_mb_pmd_1

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: crypto_aesni_mb_pmd_1,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 8
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Allocated pool "priv_sess_mp_0" on socket 0
CRYPTODEV: elt_size 0 is expanded to 320

Allocated pool "sess_mp_0" on socket 0
    lcore id    Buf Size  Burst Size    Enqueued    Dequeued  Failed Enq  Failed Deq        MOps        Gbps  Cycles/Buf

           5          64          32    10000000    10000000           0           0      8.4491      4.3259      295.89
           5         128          32    10000000    10000000           0           0      6.9138      7.0798      361.59
           5         256          32    10000000    10000000           0           0      5.2645     10.7816      474.88
           5         512          32    10000000    10000000           0           0      3.5384     14.4931      706.54
           5        1024          32    10000000    10000000           0           0      2.1451     17.5729     1165.43
           5        2048          32    10000000    10000000           0           0      1.1839     19.3968     2111.69
```

Comment: can you re-run the test with QAT 1) isolated CPU mask 2) and use one crypto QAT device (similar to SW crypto). Can you please update the result

Comment: Can't test with 1 QAT device I think.                                                                                                


CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: 0000:3d:02.7_qat_asym,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 0
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Number of needed queue pairs is higher than the maximum number of queue pairs per device.
Lower the number of cores or increase the number of crypto devices
USER1: Failed to initialise requested crypto device type
```

Comment: Using all  cores from same NUMA, I get a bit better results... however its still a lot lower than what is present in the DPDK doc.

Comment: looks like a platform and config issue, and as mentioned if you wanted to compare sw you should compare similar configuration and setup. Happy to have a look at the same if you share the debug

Comment: Yes, looks like that... I ran my application using sw_crypto.. I am getting the same Tput as I was getting without crypto enabled.. so problem is somewhere in QAT config

Comment: If you are able to share via zoom, skype I happy to look at it. I can update running the same test with Intel Broadwell and QAT 82XX engine and compare against yours too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the logs and live to debug it is concluded the `performance is in line with the expected values of both SW and HW`. Following are the reasons variation

1. QAT HW crypto is done on Xeon cascade lake cores
2. SW Crypto is run on corei7 11th gen platform
3. Core clocks on corei7 goes up to 5Ghz with turbo boost
4. HW crypto is run with CPU cores from remote NUMA
5. HW crypto is limited with memory controller to use with `-n 4`
6. HW crypto runs for a total of `30000000` and SW crypto is run for `10000000`
7. HW crypto devices are 3 but lcores passed is 5 causing 2 lcores to share the same HW.
8. ***HW crypto is done over 3 VF hence total capacity should be summed up rather than individual results.***

With these the right command to use is

HW: `./dpdk-test-crypto-perf --socket-mem 2048,1 --legacy-mem -l 4,6 -w 0000:3d:01.0 -- --buffer-sz 64,128,256,512,1024,2048 --optype cipher-then-auth --ptest throughput --auth-key-sz 64 --cipher-key-sz 16 --cipher-iv-sz 16 --auth-op generate --burst-sz 32 --total-ops 30000000 --silent --digest-sz 20 --auth-algo sha1-hmac --cipher-algo aes-cbc --cipher-op encrypt --devtype crypto_qat`

SW: `./dpdk-test-crypto-perf --socket-mem 2048,1 --legacy-mem -l 4,6 --vdev crypto_aesni_mb_pmd_1 -a 0000:00:00.0 -- --buffer-sz 64,128,256,512,1024,2048 --optype cipher-then-auth --ptest throughput --auth-key-sz 64 --cipher-key-sz 16 --cipher-iv-sz 16 --auth-op generate --burst-sz 32 --total-ops 30000000 --silent --digest-sz 20 --auth-algo sha1-hmac --cipher-algo aes-cbc --cipher-op encrypt --devtype crypto_aesni_mb`

for 64B on Xeon (3.1Ghz) we were able to get 3.2Gbps, while corei7 (5Ghz) with SW was able to get 4.2Gbps. with 2048B HW on Xeon were able to achieve 50Gbps while SW 19.2Gbps.

Note: in Xeon there are drops for enqueue and dequeue, which can be reduced with platform and BIOS settings further.